# Create text file from a batch script using a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that will generate blank text files for me using today's date and a user entered count variable(ex:1,2,3, etc) that it appends to the end of the date so that files have different names. This is what I have in my batch file so far -

```
@echo off
set /p id="Enter today's count: "
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%x  
set today=%MyDate:~0,4%%MyDate:~4,2%%MyDate:~6,2%
set filename=%today%_%id%
utility>>"%filename%.txt"
```

Although this generates the files the way I want them, I get the following -

```
'utility' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What does it mean? Is this something I should be concerned of and how can I avoid it

Comment: What are you expecting the line utility>>"%filename%.txt" to do?

Comment: It's your batch with the command utility first in the last line. If you want to create an empty file : `type NUL >%filename%.txt`

Comment: `echo utility >> "%filename%.txt"` if you want to write the word itself.

Comment: @Richard To create a text file named as the string contained in the filename variable

Comment: @AlexK. This works, thanks

Comment: You might find it easier to use `%DATE%`, (and doing appropriate processing on that result) instead of calling `wmic os get locaedatetime`

Comment: @abelenky the problem with the `%date%` variable is that its format depends on the locale (and language?) settings so it could give some portability issues